# MVC3 Dropdown Menu Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, drop-down-menu, controller

I have a model for a drop down menu similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9222292/807223). I am trying to create a controller for it.

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!";
        return View(new MyData());
    }
```

And I create my View like this

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.State,
new SelectList(Model.StateList, "Value", "Text"))
```

But I am receiving the error below for the line above:

```
Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Projects.Models.MyData>' does not contain a definition for 'StateList' and no extension method 'StateList' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Projects.Models.MyData>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Can you please direct me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: MyData is very similar to the one in the link provided

Comment: how about you'r model declaration in the view?

Comment: i inferred from the exception that you are passing a List<T> as Model and not an object of type MyData.

Comment: In my controller I have return View(new MyData()). Is it now suppose to pass the object? How can I then solve this please?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20074/discussion-between-behnam-esmaili-and-jpo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is `@model List<ProjectName.Models.MyData>`
simply change it to

```
@model Projects.Models.MyData
```

cheers!